# How to send JSON from a checkbox form

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, servlets, checkbox

I coded this, which is working but I think there is a better way to do this.. I have a form where the user can check from checkboxes. For each checkbox I have multiple info that I want to send to my servlet, so I thought to create manually a JSON...

```
<input name="warehouse" 
       value="{ 'version':'<%=b.getVersion()%>', 
                'product':'<%=b.getProduct()%>', 
                'productionDate':'<%=b.getProductionDate()%>', 
                'order':'<%=b.getOrder()%>' 
               }"  
       type="checkbox">
```

Then in my servlet, I read the checkboxes...

```
 String[] product = request.getParameterValues("warehouse");
```

I replace the `"` with `'`

```
product.replace("'","\"");
```

and then I convert every String in JSON by:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Box box = mapper.readValue(product, Box.class);
```

Is there a better way than the above to send the all these info to my servlet?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about codereview and should be ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I didn't know that there was such a site!